# l - menu block adding a class or id

Tags: drupal, menu, module, drupal-7

I am using the d7 version of menu block.

http://drupal.org/project/menu_block/

And I would like to  a class to the ul of the menu, I know I can 
hook into template_preprocess_menu_block_wrapper(&$variables) but this adds it to the wrapper.

Or is it possible to write my own wrapper and make the menu template choose my one instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use one of the following answers, [first answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/27303) and [second answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/2270).

Hope this helps... Muhammad.